# 2007-06-17 09:05:34.813 - date format needs conversion

Tags: ms-access

Need this format: 2007-06-17 09:05:34.813 modified in MS Access to be like this:
mm/dd/yyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM

Tried this in my Access query: 
"newdate": Format([newdate],"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source format is not a date, so your formula doesn't work. You need to remove number after dot:

```
Format(Left([newdate],InStr(1,[newdate],".")-1),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss AMPM")
```

Comment: The format should read `"mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss AM/PM"`, and a true date value of `2007-06-17 09:05:34.813` would in VBA for display be rounded to `2007-06-17 09:05:35`.

Comment: Just a side note: 2007-06-17 09:05:34.813 - "number after the dot" I think that was the milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, this is milliseconds